# Example string to test input boxes

Tags: html, validation

Does anyone have a string they paste in when when testing html forms?

Just basically something that will test their system handles every kind of crap data that can be passed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test cases for check input boxes are:

1. No data
2. Very large data
3. Integer data
4. Integer data with leading or trailing spaces
5. Alpha numeric data
6. Special character
7. Unicode characters
8. Html or xml data
9. SQL Injection check

Answer (score 0):

First of all if its a mandatory field check for empty data and data with spaces only.

Try pasting `<xml>` in your text box and then submit.

You have to validate against these kind of data.

Read more on

[Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)