# Testing user input with selenium

Tags: java, php, selenium-webdriver, testng, functional-testing

I'm a student that's employed by a University to write tests to verify if code can be put into production on a website. Basically, I compare a series of expected results with what they actually return. One of the areas that I'm supposed to test is a forms page that has several fields where the user can input information, such as:

```
<div class="label">Title: </div>
<div class="html"><input id="title" size="40" name="title" type="text" value="" /></div>
```

I need to test various inputs that **might** break this code or cause problems. I was just going to make an array of Strings and test them but I'm having trouble thinking of good ideas of what to put inside it.

I already told them I think they should put a limit on the size of a String that can be input by the user, but after that I'm not sure exactly what I'd want to check.

If anyone could recommend a list of Strings or something that is commonly used in tests like this I would appreciate it.

Comment: This question is way too broad! This https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 might be a start for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here similar Question answered here , might help
[Example string to test input boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357116/example-string-to-test-input-boxes)

you can try all sort of Numeric Input/Text Input combinations with special chars.

or if you want to try CSS (Cross Site Scripting) try strings like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('pwnd');</script>
```

Read more on

[Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Thanks! Those ideas are what I was looking for.